# Flex mobile using Swiz framework

Tags: apache-flex, swiz

I am investigating an flex mobile application using SWIZ framework.
However, I have no experience with all frameworks.
Where can I know what is it and have a quick start?
I know that it is using MVC but no more.
Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find information on the Swiz Framework at the [Swiz framework](http://swizframework.org/) site.  Specifically look at the [documentation wiki](http://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Home).